# script to rename bulk files for administration office

Tags: batch-file, rename

Every day I'm scanning up to 300 documents for clients and rename them manually. All of them are bills (incoming) ore invoices (outgoing).

It should be very nice to have a file ore button to click on. After clicking this button should ask me a *client number*, *year*, *month*, *type of invoice* and an *invoice number to start from*.

[image: Examplepicture]

After submitting the filename is `20181-2015-10-INK-000018.pdf`:
`20181` (*client number*)`-2015` (*year*)`-10` (*month*)`-INK` (*type of invoice*)`-000018` (*invoice number*).

Comment: You might want to provide a lot more detail.  From your explanation I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Your edit does not make it any clearer.  What do the input file names look like?  Where are we getting the client number from?  Where are we getting the year and month from? Is the year and month in the original file name or are we to use the current year and month?  Where are we getting the invoice type from?  Where is the invoice number coming from?

Comment: If you cannot answer any of my questions then nobody is going to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Place this Batch file in the same folder where the *.pdf files are. You may execute it via double-click if you wish, or open a cmd.exe window, navigate to the desired folder and enter the name of the Batch file

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Select the folder where this Batch file is
cd "%~P0"

echo Enter:   Clientnumber Year Month Type Start-number   separated by space
set /P "input="
for /F "tokens=1-5" %%a in ("%input%") do (
   set "Client=%%a"
   set "Year=%%b"
   set "Month=%%c"
   set "Type=%%d"
   set "Number=%%e"
)

set /A "Number+=1000000"
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B *.pdf') do (
   ECHO ren "%%a" "%Client%-%Year%-%Month%-%Type%-!Number:~1!.pdf"
   set /A "Number+=1"
)

pause
```

Note that this program just *display* the `ren` commands. Test it, and if the ren commands looks correct, remove the `ECHO` part in order to *execute* the ren commands.

Comment: i should yust remove @echo off?

Comment: No. Change this line: `ECHO ren "%%a" "%Client%-%Year%-%Month%-%Type%-!Number:~1!.pdf"` by this one: `ren "%%a" "%Client%-%Year%-%Month%-%Type%-!Number:~1!.pdf"`

Comment: May I ask you to both select and upvote this answer? Thanks!